# Python --- multiplication in GF(2) field

Tags: python, python-2.7, polynomial-math, finite-field

This function is returning unusual values in the list g.  It should return 32774, 65548, 1048768 but instead it's values are more like it's treating the entire binary like a big slinky and just moving the LSB's towards the MSB's instead of actually shifting.

Here's the function:

```
def multiply(a,b): #a,b are values like 1101010001....
    a = min(a,b); b = max(a,b)
    g = []; bitsa = "{0:b}".format(a)  #returns product of 2 polynomials in gf2
    [g.append((b<<i)*int(bit)) for i,bit in enumerate(bitsa)]
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,g)
```

This is what I'm testing with:

```
x = int(str(100000000000011),2)
y = int(str(1000110),2)
x1 = int(str(111),2)
y1 = int(str(11),2)
x2 = int(str(0001),2)
y2 = int(str(1111),2)
print "multiply: ",multiply(x,y)
print "multiply: ",multiply(x1,y1)
print "multiply: ",multiply(x2,y2)
```

Only x1,y1 works right now, the others don't.
This is the whole equation for the last input:

```
      100000000000011
              1000110
---------------------
     100000000000011 
    100000000000011  
100000000000011      
---------------------
100011000000011001010
```

So as you can see, to get the product, both binaries need to have their indexes checked for 1's and then append based on that.  I'm not sure how to fit that part in, and how to do it so it returns the correct value.  Trying to understand why x1,y1 works and the others don't.

EDIT:

I just want it to be clear that J0HN's answer appears to be completely accurate and furthermore he caught an error in the online tool that was referenced.  From what it appears now, the built-in's are preferential when working with finite field math in this way. Anyone happening across this should definitely consider showing him some vote love for those keen observation skills-to-pay-the-bills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `enumerate` wrong. It starts form the MSB, so

```
for i, bit in enumerate('110'):
     print (i, bit)
```

would yield `(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0)`, not `(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)`.

Aside from that, some style suggestions:

- [Please avoid using `;` in python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Search for `Compound statements` on the page
- [Use list comprehensions if possible](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)
- Either the comment is wrong, or you forgot to mention that you `multiply` operates on lists. If former - remove it, it's very confusing. If latter - your existing code wont work at all as there are no `<<` operator defined on lists.

So, `multiply` better written and fixed:

```
def multiply(a,b):
    bitsa = reversed("{0:b}".format(a))
    g = [(b<<i)*int(bit) for i,bit in enumerate(bitsa)]
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,g)
```

Also, as a final suggestion, why wouldn't you allow python do the things for you? It has built-in support for arbitrary long integers, so all your examples are equvivalent to just `a*b`, or, if you want the result to be in binary form `"{0:b}".format(a*b)`

Comment: thanks, the comment should now be correct. you're right, i was going to use the built-in, but it appears that this doesn't work for the x1,y1 combination and therefore seemed questionable.  the min,max statements were needed (i think because it's iterating over the largest value). it's still not working for the last case, refer to this unb.edu calculator (preset to the values for testing), also please check this calculator for the x1,y1 to see the difference between the built-in and this ----  http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=100000000000011&den=1000110&f=m&e=1&p=1&m=1

Comment: I'm afraid that tool you use get it wrong, in the example it misses the carryover from 3rd digit to fourth. Is it supposed to be so carryovers are ignored? Also, if it's supposed to operate on lists - the `multiply` as you have it now won't do it, as, again, there are no `<<` operator defined on lists.

Comment: x1*y1 gives 1001, and with the carryover it should be 1101. but that's still not the 10101 that the built-in gives. so then this is also wrong --- http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=1000110&den=100000000000011&f=d&e=1&p=1&m=1  ---- in the built-in print "{0:b}".format(x/y),"{0:b}".format(x%y)  returns 11101010 111, so is the built-in right and this tool does not seem to be properly processing the binary for every test example?

Comment: Yes, looks like that tool is just broken.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't multiplying in GF(2) just bit wise and? So couldn't you just do:

```
x = int("1001",2)
y = int("1010",2)
z = x&y
print "{0:b}".format(z)
```

Comment: No it's not, it's essentially a product.